# My Web Application suddenly gone (SOLVED)

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, sharepoint-server

Yesterday, I used my SharePoint sites, and there were no problems. But, about 1 hour ago, when I tried to access it, an error message appeared, it's as if the application did not exist.
Then I opened up my SharePoint Central Administration, I was surprised knowing the application no longer exists. 
I don't know where to start finding the clue, since I'm still new to SharePoint Development. Please guide me on this, at least where I should start looking for the error.

[image: The display on Sharepoint Central Admin]

When I look into the Central Admin, there is message :
[image]

And then I click the link to get detailed information :
[image]

Probably one of these error message is the root cause, but I don't know where to start looking at.

PS :
I have solved this case. I recreated the site, and then replace the new database (I use WSS_Content) with the old one, and finally it's solved :)

Comment: What is the last action you have perform in your application?

Comment: Didn't someone run a backup/restore of the config DB behind your back?

Comment: As I remember, I just added a new workflow to my newly created list.

Comment: What if I try to recreate the site? Will this solution solve the problem? I mean, if I try to create new site, will the old data be replaced or reused?